# Which of these two sentences is correct: they need to understand the lesson well,or they need to understand well the lesson?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentence is correct: They need to understand the lesson well, or they need to understand well the lesson.

Comment: *"They need to understand the lesson well"* is the one that 99% of all native English speakers use. But the other order isn't strictly ungrammatical. The rule is to only put an adverb between the verb and the object when the object is long (I'd say five words or more, but this is a matter of judgment).

Answer (score -1):

The sentence which is grammatically correct is: '***They need to understand the lesson well***' because '*understand*' is a transitive verb and is followed by the direct object '*the lesson*'.
'*Well*' is the adverbial modifier and can follow the intransitive verb, for example, '*He works well*', or the object of the sentence like yours.

Comment: But would you put *well* at the end of the sentence *"They need to understand tomorrow's lesson about where to look for mushrooms and how to tell edible ones from poisonous ones well"*? Or would *"well"* work better immediately after *"understand"* in that sentence.

Comment: This is a special case with a long objective group when the traditional order of words can be changed for the reader's comfort.

Comment: It's not traditional. The rule "don't put adverbs between the verb and the object" is fairly new. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=became+immediately+the%2C+immediately+became+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbecame%20immediately%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmediately%20became%20the%3B%2Cc0). The phrase *"became immediately the"* today has frequency 5% of what it had in 1800. Even 50 years ago, I believe both of the OP's sentences would generally have been considered grammatical.